# Want to show name instead of id in the URL field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I don't want to show `/route_name/{id}` in the URL field of my Laravel project. Instead of that I want to show `/route_name/{name}` but pass the `id` in the back-end to the controller.

Suppose I have a route named `departments` and pass an id `3` named `knee_pain` as a parameter. And it is like `/departments/3`

But I want to to show `/departments/knee_pain` in my url and as well as want to pass the id `3` in my controller without showing the `id` in the `url`.

How to do that ?

Comment: You need to intake the name and resolve the id in your endpoint method/controller (via a database call probably). Then use the id for whatever you want. (Assuming you have a 1 to 1 relation between name and id). is that a GET endpoint?

Comment: in how many routes you want to have that treatment?

Comment: @ Bentaye...Will you please give me a sample code for better understand ?

Comment: @JoseSilva....Almost all routes of the project ... :(

Answer (score 2):

In your model you can use the **getRouteKeyName** method to bind to another attribute than the default **id** in your routes :

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug'; // Default is 'id'.
}
```

Rather than using the name attribute, that you could use elsewhere in your application for displaying the name of the entry, I recommend using an attribute made url friendly. You could use Str::slug() for that.

```
public function setNameAttribute($value) {
    $this->name = $value;
    $this->slug = \Str::slug($value);
}
```

It will 'slugify' your string, for example : \Str::slug('Knee pain') => 'knee-pain'.

**Note :** in Laravel 5.5, use the str_slug() helper.

You should also make sure this string is unique in your database.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to garantee that the name is unique, if don't you will have more than one Id in your controller. For that i recommend you to use Purifier to remove spaces and make it URL friendly:
[Purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier)

Second, probably the best way to have clean controllers is creating a middleware that understand what kind of name is (what table should middleware look for). You can validate that by route name and send the correct id to controller.

[Middleware docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)

Comment: @JoseSilva.......Thanks for the suggestion. I will accept your answer after successfully completed my task ... :)

Comment: @JoseSilva.....your suggestion can't solve my issue....may be you can't properly understand my problem brother .

Comment: @raff as i understand, you want to have a name in url foo.bo/{string} and still receive an id in your controller. Am i right? Show me code and i can help you with that

Comment: how to apply only for specific routes??

Comment: @VPR set the middleware only for those routes or group routes. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes